# text and xml converting problems

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, parsing, text

I have some problem with texts and xml. I’m using Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (x86_64).
I have string x and convert it into xml format.

But the input and output are different. I assume python converts  & lt; into < which I do not want.

Here's how the result looks like:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
x = '<SCRIPT>g(x) &lt;0</SCRIPT>' 
root = ET.fromstring(x)
print('result : ',root.text[5])
```

---

and the result is

```
result :  <
```

---

which is showing that & lt; has been changed. I'd like it to be

```
&
```

Thank you!!!!

Comment: Please post your code using markup, not as a link and happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

If XML has the value `<SCRIPT>g(x) <0</SCRIPT>` it will lead to parsing error. In order to avoid such errors, The `<` symbol is replaced with an entity reference `&lt;`

Similar entity references includes:

```
&lt;    <   less than
&gt;    >   greater than
&amp;   &   ampersand 
&apos;  '   apostrophe
&quot;  "   quotation mark
```

To get back the entity reference after XML parsing, we can use string replace.

`print('result : ',root.text.replace('<','&lt;')[5])`

Hope this helps.